# Adding 'int' and 'str' in python, What should I change to fix it

Tags: python-3.x, string, integer

```
class cards(object):
    
    suit_dict = {
                 "d" : "Diamonds"  , "h" : "Hearts" , "c" : "clubs" , "s" : "Spades"
        }
    
    values_dict = { 1: 'Ace',

                  2: 2,

                  3: 3,

                  4: 4,

                  5: 5,

                  6: 6,

                  7: 7,

                  8: 8,

                  9: 9,

                  10: 10,

                  11: 'Jack',

                  12: 'Queen',

                  13: 'King'
                 }
    
    
    def __init__(self,values,suits):
        suits = suits.lower
        self.values = values
        self.suits = suits
        
    def __str__(self):
        my_card = str(self.values_dict[self.values]) + "of"  + self.suit_dict[self.suits]
        return my_card

his_card = cards(2, "D")

print(his_card)
```

So like I am getting an error about adding strings and integers; I am not sure about what to change to make it work properly.

```
    my_card = self.values_dict[self.values] + "of"  + self.suit_dict[self.suits]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I tried making str(self.values_dict[self.values]), but now I get a different type of error.

```
    my_card = str(self.values_dict[self.values]) + "of"  + self.suit_dict[self.suits]

KeyError: <built-in method lower of str object at 0x000001536717F830>
```

Comment: ``suits.lower`` looks up the method ``lower``. ``suits.lower()`` looks up the method *and executes it* to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding parantheses to your lower method allowed the code to work for me.

As below:

```
    def __init__(self,values,suits):
        self.values = values
        self.suits = suits.lower()
```

Comment: No worries, as the comment above says you need to execute the method otherwise it won't work.